# Vectorized vs Non Vectorized Product gives different result . Why?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

The dot product of two arrays gives different results by vectorized and non vectorized approach. Can anyone explain: why the last decimal digits are different for the result?

```py
# Matrix Multiplication (x_2*x_1) by Vectorised vs Non-Vectorised approach.

x_1 = [9, 2, 5, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 2, 5, 0, 0]

x_2 = np.random.rand(3,len(x_1)) # Random (3,len(x_1)) numpy array

#  1) Non Vectorized Approach

non_vectorized_prod = np.zeros(x_2.shape[0])
for i in range(x_2.shape[0]):
    for j in range(len(x_1)):
        non_vectorized_prod[i] += x_2[i,j]*x_1[j]
print("The non vectorised dot product is :", non_vectorized_prod)

# 2) Vectorized Approach
vectorized_prod = np.dot(x_2,x_1)
print("The vectorized dot product is :",vectorized_prod,
     "\nThe vectorized and non vectorized dot product is","equal." if (non_vectorized_prod == vectorized_prod).all() else "not equal.")
```

```
Output :
The non vectorised dot product is : [22.42781552623253  26.510577832963094 20.285766898773222]
The vectorized dot product is : [22.42781552623252  26.510577832963094 20.285766898773225] 
The vectorized and non vectorized dot product is not equal.
```

As from the output we can see the first and third elements are different in vectorized vs non vectorized dot product. Any explanation ?

Comment: You are running into the limits of a double precision floating point number. Its almost never a good idea to compare floats directly by equality; instead you should compare them up to some desired threshold using, for example, [np.isclose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)

Comment: @Tyberius Thanks for explanation.